# $V dV = \frac{1}{2} d(V^2)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm following a derivation of the Bernoulli Equation for fluid flows from a book and at one point it says - "Noting that $V dV = \frac{1}{2} d(V^2)$"...

How is this derived?

Here is what I would do -

$V dV = \frac{1}{2} d(V^2)$

$V \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}(V^2)$

$V \frac{dV}{dt} = V$

But these aren't equal as the LHS is some fraction of $V$. So what am I doing wrong or not understanding correctly?

Comment: $d/dt\ne d/dV$!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with what you know such as $$\frac{d(V^2)}{dV}  = 2V$$ then rearrange to 
$$\frac12\frac{d(V^2)}{dV}  = V$$ and if you think it meaningful $$\frac12 \; d(V^2)  = V \; dV.$$

If you want to take the derivative with respect to $t$ then by the chain rule $\frac{d(V^2)}{dt}  = 2V\frac{dV}{dt}$ so:  $$\frac12 \frac{d(V^2)}{dt}  = V\frac{dV}{dt}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(V) = \frac{1}{2}V^2$. Then $\frac{df}{dV} = V$. Now, treating the derivative on the LHS as a ratio of differentials, you can "bring over" the $dV$ to give $df = VdV$. Since $f(V) = \frac{1}{2}V^2$, you can now say $d(\frac{1}{2}V^2) = VdV$. The constant term can be brought outside the differential to finally yield $\frac{1}{2}d(V^2) = VdV$.

Basically, it's about getting used to manipulating differentials (Leibniz notation).